# Spring boot 1.3.1 with Tyrus websocket causes Authentication Exception

Tags: authentication, websocket, spring-boot, tyrus

We recently migrated to Spring boot 1.3.1 from the traditional spring project.
Our existing clients use Tyrus 1.12 as a websocket client.

After the upgrade, we found that the clients no longer connect and throws AuthenticationException. Strangely, they are able to connect for the first time since server restart and soon after throws AuthenticationException. 
Digging a bit more, I found that Tyrus receives a 401 initially and passes on credentials subsequently. The server logs indicate the same behaviour, by first assigning ROLE_ANONYMOUS and then the correct role, ROLE_GUEST there after.

It seems like after the negotiation, the server closes connection and disconnects.

I observed the same behaviour when using spring stomp websocket client with Tyrus.

```
  ClientManager container = ClientManager.createClient();
        container.getProperties().put("org.glassfish.tyrus.client.sharedContainer", true);
        container.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.CREDENTIALS, new Credentials("guest", "guest"));
        StandardWebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient(container);
        final CountDownLatch messageLatch = new CountDownLatch(10);
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(webSocketClient);
```

This same server setup works fine when the credentials are sent in the header.

```
stompClient.connect(url,  getHandshakeHeaders("guest", "guest"), handler);
```

And this **will NOT work** since the credentials are not in the header

```
ListenableFuture<StompSession>session = stompClient.connect(url, handler, "localhost", "8080");
```

I am not understanding why it is working one way and not the other.

After upgrading to spring-boot, our software is no longer backwards compatible and will have to ask all our external clients to inject the authorization in the header before receiving a 401.

Can someone please help?

[My earlier post with stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332080/spring-boot-authentication-with-tyrus-websocket-client-causes-authenticationexce)

Comment: Afaik, you are asking for preemptive authentication - and that's what you are doing by "injecting" headers. I'm not sure what part of the flow is your client, you can do that in your code. Anyway, not doing preemptive authentication is perfectly fine (I'm Tyrus developer) - the issue seems to be more on the server side; you need to figure out why is the server closing the connection after receiving request with proper auth headers.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation is inline with my observations. Will wait for a solution from the spring boot community